# When dropdown item is selected show as active Flask Jinja Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2

I'm a bit stuck.

I have a flask form

```
class RegistrationForm(Form):
    age  = RadioField('Label', choices=[('0','A'), ('1','B'), ('2','C')])
```

What I'm trying to do in my jinja template is when some one selects their age it shows it as the active div.  And passes it on the form submit.

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@pny.db_session
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

But this where I run into my problem

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Age
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>{{ form.age }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

It shows the radio bubbles, but when I select them it doesn't make it the active div.  And also its not showing the number associated with the age.

I am trying to make the

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>{{ form.age }}</li>
```

show the selection that the users selects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please make your question more clear. Where is the `div` in your code which you want to make active ?

Comment: @PralhadNarsinhSonar updated, thought it was clear.  I am trying to have what the user selects as their age in the dropdown menu show as active and pass it to the form when they click submit

Comment: Try  `{{ form.age() }}` it should generate an `ul` with as many `li`s as options you have specified.

Comment: I just updated, it shows the proper number of lists.  But when you select it it does not show as the active, it still shows "age" vs say a, b, c, etc